# Complements to reducible plane projective curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

Hello,

Suppose that $C_1,C_2\subset\mathbb P^2$ are projective curves (over $\mathbb C$); $C_1$ and $C_2$ may be reducible but they must not have a common component. Let $L\subset \mathbb P^2$ be a line in general position, and denote by $H$ the kernel of the natural epimorphism $\pi_1(\mathbb P^2\setminus(C_1\cup C_2))\to \pi_1(\mathbb P^2\setminus C_1)$.

Is it true that $H$ is the smallest normal subgroup in $\pi_1(\mathbb P^2\setminus(C_1\cup C_2))$ containg small loops in $L$ around the points of $L\cap C_2$?

Thank you in advance,
Serge

Comment: If $C_1\cup C_2$ has only normal crossings, the answer is positive; I am not sure otherwise. 

Comment: @Misha: you bet it's positive in this case, when `$\pi_1$` is commutative and generated by loops about components:) If I am not mistaken, the answer is also positive if $C_2$ has only normal crossings and each component of $C_2$ is transversal to $C_1$. I wonder what happens in general...